# Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?

Tags: python, list

I've noticed that many operations on lists that modify the list's contents will return `None`, rather than returning the list itself. Examples:

```
>>> mylist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> empty = mylist.clear()
>>> restored = mylist.extend(range(3))
>>> backwards = mylist.reverse()
>>> with_four = mylist.append(4)
>>> in_order = mylist.sort()
>>> without_one = mylist.remove(1)
>>> mylist
[0, 2, 4]
>>> [empty, restored, backwards, with_four, in_order, without_one]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

**What is the thought process behind this decision?**

To me, it seems hampering, since it prevents "chaining" of list processing (e.g. `mylist.reverse().append('a string')[:someLimit]`). I imagine it might be that "The Powers That Be" decided that list comprehension is a better paradigm (a valid opinion), and so didn't want to encourage other methods - but it seems perverse to prevent an intuitive method, even if better alternatives exist.

---

<sub>This question is specifically about Python's *design decision* to return `None` from mutating list methods like `.append`. However, novices often write incorrect code that expects `.append` (in particular) to return the same list that was just modified. **Please do** close such questions as a duplicate of this one, however. "The code did the wrong thing because the result was `None` rather than the list" is something that the OP in these cases *should have discovered independently* via debugging; creating a proper [MRE](/help/minimal-reproducible-example) leaves behind a question like this one - therefore, it can be considered a duplicate.</sub>

<sub>See [How can I collect the results of a repeated calculation in a list, dictionary etc. (or make a copy of a list with each element modified)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408) for the simple question of "**how** do I append to a list repeatedly?" (or debugging questions that boil down to that problem). This is a new canonical that has been specifically prepared to address the topic with the perspective that beginners lack.</sub>

<sub>To get modified versions of the list, see:</sub>

- [How to allow list append() method to return the new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902980)
- [How can I get a sorted copy of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573507)
- [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421) (to replace `.extend`)
- [A quick way to return list without a specific element in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738700) (to replace `.remove`)
- [How can I get a reversed copy of a list (avoid a separate statement when chaining a method after .reverse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691)

<sub>The same issue applies to some methods of other built-in data types, e.g. `set.discard` (see [How to remove specific element from sets inside a list using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877032)) and `dict.update` (see [Why doesn't a python dict.update() return the object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452995/)).</sub>

<sub>The same reasoning applies to designing your own APIs. See [Is making in-place operations return the object a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062423).</sub>

Comment: See also: [Why does not the + operator change a list while .append() does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748158)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, I suspect that "This question **is** an appropriate closure target..." was meant to be left as a comment or metadata, rather than as part of the edited question? Regardless - can you elaborate on why you think this question should be closed? I _had_ created a MRE, I knew what the behaviour _was_ and how to work around it - I was asking about the design philosophy that led to that behaviour being implemented in the language, not about "how to achieve the goal I wanted", and I suspect others will find that philosophy interesting too.

Comment: No; I mean that it is appropriate to close **other** questions (specifically, ones of the sort described in the previous sentence) *as duplicates of this*. If I thought this question should be closed, I would have voted to close it.

Comment: Ah, got it - thanks! I misunderstood the meaning of "closure target".

Comment: I tried to improve the wording, because it should be as clear as possible to everyone.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The general design principle in Python is for **functions that mutate an object in-place to return `None`**. I'm not sure it would have been the design choice I'd have chosen, but it's basically to emphasise that a new object is not returned.

Guido van Rossum (our Python BDFL) states the design choice [on the Python-Dev mailing list](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html):

> I'd like to explain once more why I'm so adamant that sort() shouldn't
> return 'self'.
>
> This comes from a coding style (popular in various other languages, I
> believe especially Lisp revels in it) where a series of side effects
> on a single object can be chained like this:
>
> ```
> x.compress().chop(y).sort(z)
> ```
>
> which would be the same as
>
> ```
> x.compress()
> x.chop(y)
> x.sort(z)
> ```
>
> I find the chaining form a threat to readability; it requires that the
> reader must be intimately familiar with each of the methods.  The
> second form makes it clear that each of these calls acts on the same
> object, and so even if you don't know the class and its methods very
> well, you can understand that the second and third call are applied to
> x (and that all calls are made for their side-effects), and not to
> something else.
>
> I'd like to reserve chaining for operations that return new values,
> like string processing operations:
>
> ```
> y = x.rstrip("\n").split(":").lower()
> ```
>
> There are a few standard library modules that encourage chaining of
> side-effect calls (pstat comes to mind).  There shouldn't be any new
> ones; pstat slipped through my filter when it was weak.

Comment: "pstat slipped through my filter when it was weak." I love it. [`pstats`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-pstats) remains to this day as the one that got away: `stats.strip_dirs().add()` => `<pstats.Stats object at 0x0000018866977640>`

Comment: Coming back to this _ten years_ after it was written (thanks for the excellent illustrative edit, @Karl Knechtel!), Guido's response _to that paradigm_ is, indeed, reasonable. However, having fallen in love with FP over that time, I feel like it's a strawman - if _no_ methods mutate an object in-place but always return a new object, then the code being chained could instead be expressed by: `x1 = x.compress(); x2=x1.chop(y); x3 = x2.sort(z)` - which, I claim, is much more intuitively replaced with a chain.

That said - Python isn't FP (mostly? intentionally?), so paradigm doesn't apply.

Comment: Or, to rephase - "The general design principle in Python is for functions that mutate an object in-place to return None" is a true statement, but does nothing to explain _why_ these operations mutate in-place.

Comment: Upvoted for accuracy of explanation (and would like to downvote Guido's design choices if that were. possible) I am glad that Guido is [mostly?] gone: exactly this pattern that he does not like is the [superior] basis to [most] languages that support functionals programming.  We're left with the fallout.

Answer (score 20):

I can't speak for the developers, but I find this behavior very intuitive.

If a method works on the original object and modifies it in-place, it doesn't return anything, because there is no new information - you obviously already have a reference to the (now mutated) object, so why return it again?

If, however, a method or function creates a new object, then of course it has to return it.

So `l.reverse()` returns nothing (because now the list has been reversed, but the identfier `l` still points to that list), but `reversed(l)` has to return the newly generated list because `l` still points to the old, unmodified list.

EDIT: I just learned from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682601) that this principle is called [Command-Query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation).

Comment: This is obviously a mindset that I need to aim to cultivate, because my initial reaction to "...so why return it again?" was "why not?". To my mind, returning a reference allows a different technique ("chaining") without preventing any other technique (sequential modifications), so it would only be "worse" if chaining itself is "bad".  However, arguments put forward in other comments (by Guido himself, no less!) assert that chaining is, indeed, bad.

Thank you for your input! I really enjoying learning from people who know what they're talking about!

Comment: @scubbo: The Zen of Python (`import this`) states that "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."; this helps answering the "Why not?" a little bit. Although I must admit that there are several areas in Python where "There's more than one way to do it." appears to have been the guiding principle :)

Comment: I wish my past-self had thought to include the link to "comments by Guido" :( also, Tim, your first link to "another answer" also links to the Wikipedia page (though I suspect that you, too, currently lack the context to correct that)

Comment: The alternative is 'fluent' notation (call chaining) e.g. PHP, Scala, R tidyverse, also sometimes implemented in JS, Java, C++. *"I find this behavior very intuitive"* is not a reason, it's a circular argument; you wouldn't if you'd learned the fluent paradigm. (Whether fluent is worse/better e.g. for maintainability, multithreading, etc. is a whole other very active debate.)

Answer (score 3):

One could argue that the signature itself makes it clear that the function mutates the list rather than returning a new one: if the function returned a list, its behavior would have been much less obvious.

Comment: Were type hints (and so, "peeks" at signature definitions in IDEs) in widespread use at that time? If not, I feel that it's unreasonable to expect a programmer to be regularly thinking about the signature of a method if they can't observe it with a mouseover/shortcut-key - I would have thought they would just assume the signature fits their expectations.

Or was it possible to display signature definitions in IDEs without (prior to) type hints? I only really started using IDEs after type hints were popular, so I never put that to the test.

Comment: The `typing` module was only added in 3.5, initially released in 2015. IDEs would have to have started with their own database of type information about builtins etc. I think the argument is simply "knowing that the function returns `None` is a reminder that it mutates the object"; but I think the logic would more likely work the other way around. Aside from that, the names are *supposed* to be chosen in a way that makes it obvious which methods are commands and which are queries (per the "command-query separation" model cited elsewhere).

Answer (score 3):

### If you were sent here after asking for help fixing your code:

In the future, [please try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to look for problems in the code yourself, by [carefully studying](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) what happens when the code runs. Rather than giving up because there is an error message, check the result of each calculation, and see where the code starts working differently from what you expect.

If you had code calling a method like `.append` or `.sort` on a list, you will notice that the *return value* is `None`, while the list is modified *in place*. Study the example carefully:

```
>>> x = ['e', 'x', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e']
>>> y = x.sort()
>>> print(y)
None
>>> print(x)
['a', 'e', 'e', 'l', 'm', 'p', 'x']
```

`y` got the special `None` value, because that is what was returned. `x` changed, because the sort happened in place.

It works this way on purpose, so that code like `x.sort().reverse()` breaks. See the other answers to understand why the Python developers wanted it that way.

### To fix the problem

First, think carefully about the intent of the code. **Should `x` change?** Do we actually need a separate `y`?

Let's consider `.sort` first. If `x` should change, then call `x.sort()` by itself, without assigning the result anywhere.

If a sorted *copy* is needed instead, use `y = x.sorted()`. See [How can I get a sorted copy of a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573507) for details.

For other methods, we can get modified copies like so:

`.clear` -> there is no point to this; a "cleared copy" of the list is just an empty list. Just use `y = []`.

`.append` and `.extend` -> probably the simplest way is to use the `+` operator. To add multiple elements from a list `l`, use `y = x + l` rather than `.extend`. To add a single element `e` *wrap it in a list first*: `y = x + [e]`. Another way in 3.5 and up is to use unpacking: `y = [*x, *l]` for `.extend`, `y = [*x, e]` for `.append`. See also [How to allow list append() method to return the new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902980) for `.append` and [How do I concatenate two lists in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1720421) for `.extend`.

`.reverse` -> First, consider whether an actual copy is needed. The built-in `reversed` gives you an *iterator* that can be used to loop over the elements in reverse order. To make an actual copy, simply pass that iterator to `list`: `y = list(reversed(x))`. See [How can I get a reversed copy of a list (avoid a separate statement when chaining a method after .reverse)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4280691) for details.

`.remove` -> Figure out the index of the element that will be removed (using `.index`), then use slicing to find the elements before and after that point and put them together. As a function:

```
def without(a_list, value):
    index = a_list.index(value)
    return a_list[:index] + a_list[index+1:]
```

(We can translate `.pop` similarly to make a modified copy, though of course `.pop` actually returns an element from the list.)

See also [A quick way to return list without a specific element in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738700).

(If you plan to remove *multiple* elements, strongly consider using a list comprehension (or `filter`) instead. It will be much simpler than any of the workarounds [needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/) for removing items from the list while iterating over it. This way also *naturally* gives a modified copy.)

---

For any of the above, of course, we can also make a modified copy by explicitly *making a copy* and then using the in-place method on the copy. The most elegant approach will depend on the context and on personal taste.