# How to create a new list, by appending a value in a certain position on and old list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a new list, which is a replica of an other list. This new list I want to modify by changing values at specific positions.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902980/allow-python-list-append-method-to-return-the-new-list), and the most upvoted answer can make a new list and add on to the old list. This is a good start, but I want to decide where the additions are done (in his version, it just adds it on to the end of the list)

What he has:

```
myList = [10,20,30] 

yourList = myList + [40]

print("your list: " + yourList)
```

> your list: [10,20,30,40]

In this instance, I would want to be able to change where the 40 in your list goes ie

> your list: [10,40,20,30]

I'm unsure how I would go about doing that. Thanks! (Pretty new here sorry if I'm not clear)

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing to split the original list apart at the desired index, then put it back together again.

For example:

```
insert_at = 1

myList = [10,20,30] 

# Uses PEP 448 unpacking generalizations to avoid excess temporary `list`s
yourList = [*myList[:insert_at], 40, *my_list[insert_at:]]

# Or via concatenation (involves an extra temporary)
yourList = myList[:insert_at] + [40] + my_list[insert_at:]

print("your list: " + yourList)
```

Alternatively, if you don't need a one-liner, copy the `list`, then call `insert` on the copy:

```
yourList = myList[:]  # myList.copy() also works on Python 3
yourList.insert(insert_at, 40)
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same list:

Use the `insert` method of the `list` class

```
myList.insert(1, 40)
```

`insert(index, element)` inserts the `element` into the list at the position `index` - shifting the remaining elements rightward as required.

To make a new list:

```
new_list = myList.copy()
new_list.insert(1, 40)
```

Comment: They seem to want to make a new `list`; `insert` modifies in place. You'd need to explicitly copy (with `myList[:]` or `myList.copy()`), then call `insert` on the copy to make this work.

Comment: That's going to change the original list though, I want to make a new list and keep the old one the same. I tried to do yourList = myList.insert(1, 40) and it just returns None (I'm pretty sure that means I can't make a new list with it then?)

Comment: @MrNielsen: That's a Python standard behavior; mutating methods always return `None` (or something other than the instance they were called on when appropriate, e.g. `dict.setdefault` and `dict.pop` return the value in question), so you're not deceived into thinking it made a modified copy.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That's exactly what I want. How do I go about copying the list though? I can't make yourList = myList because as soon as I change yourList it's also going to also change myList, but I want the old lists to stay the same.

Comment: @MrNielsen I've edited my answer to include how you can make a copy of the list (in python 3)

Comment: @MrNielsen: Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56553895/364696); it includes the necessary copying component (either the complete slice, `[:]` or the `copy()` method).

Comment: Thanks so much, @ShadowRanger and rdas the .copy() works great for what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 0):

you can copy your list and insert the value in the new list something like this:

```py
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
my_2_list = my_list.copy()
```

then i wnat to insert a vlue at position 3 i can do

```py
my_2_list.insert(3, value)
```