# appending to list in list comprehension

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the minimum of a list and float, I had the following code but it was giving error

```
x=['14.99', '14.99', '15.00', '16.36']
y=21.00
min([float(i) for i in x.append(y)])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
#x= ['14.99', '14.99', '15.00', '16.36', 21.0] y got appended
```

However, if i do (append y before list comprehension)

```
x=['14.99', '14.99', '15.00', '16.36']
y=21.00
x.append(y)
min([float(i) for i in x])
```

Output is :14.99 #correct

How can I do this in one line?

Comment: ``list.append()`` always returns ``None``, if that's what you're asking, same with most other list manipulation methods.

Comment: @MikeScotty isn't x an iterable ?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the point. You are trying to iterate the **return value** of ``x.append(y)``, which is ``None``.

Comment: @MikeScotty How can I do this in one line then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
min(y, min([float(i) for i in x]))
```

or this one is more readable

```
min(y, min(map(float, x)))
```

basically you compare the float y with the minimum of the list.

Comment: I want the minimum of the 5 items not the minimum of the list

Comment: @programmerwiz32 those will give the minimum of the 5 items. You can check by setting y=11 for example, it will give 11.

Answer (score 1):

It's very ugly in my opinion, but you can do it like that:

```
min([float(i) for i in x+[y])])
```

Comment: what is a better looking way

Comment: The "better looking way" is IMHO to keep your original code. It's more readable and should even be more efficient (appending to an existing object instead of creating a new one - or rather two new ones, since you're creating a new list from ``y`` first and then another new list from ``x`` and ``[y]``).

Comment: I would use 2 lines to be explicit: `_list = [float(i) for i in x]+[y]` and then `min(_list)`. If you do not care overwriting x, then the code you posted is the best one.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=['14.99', '14.99', '15.00', '16.36']
y=21.00
min(float(x) for x in x+[y])
```

This concatenates `y` as a list to the `x` list, and then finds the min of all of them.

See [Allow python list append method to return the new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902980/allow-python-list-append-method-to-return-the-new-list).