# python recursion appending to list

Tags: python, list, recursion, append

I am trying to to append current to master every time current changes. I have been unsuccessful using list. I have been able to to modify strings and append different strings to master but it would be much easier if I could use list.

```
master = []

def recur(count,current):
    count = count + 1
    if (count == 5):
        return
    current.append(1)
    master.append(current)
    recur(count,current)


recur(0,[])

print(master)
# out put
# [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

# what I expected
# [[1], [1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]]
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* you expected what you expected?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow list append() method to return the new list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902980/how-to-allow-list-append-method-to-return-the-new-list)

Comment: Alternatively, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Just use `master.append(current.copy())`. To understand more about the issue, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly).

Comment: As an aside, it might be best to avoid recursion for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you want:

```py
master = []

def recur(count, current):
    count += 1
    if (count == 5):
        return

    new_current = current.copy()

    new_current.append(1)
    master.append(new_current)

    recur(count, new_current)


recur(0, [])

print(master)
```

The issue is that `current` is a reference to the list object... not the actual list itself. So when you append `current` to `master` you are just appending a reference to the same list object. So when you add a new element to the `current` list it's added to the one list that all of your references are pointing to.

The solution is to take a [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/copy.html) of `current` list to store its state at that time. There are different types of [copy](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/copy.html) - deep and shallow. Shallow would make a copy of the list object but not it's elements, a deep copy will recurse through the elements and any subelements if you have a list of lists for example.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are appending the reference of the `current` list to master. So, every time you change `current` the previously appended lists also change.

Use this link for visualization:[click here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20recur%28count,curr%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20count%2B%3D1%0A%20%20%20%20if%20count%3D%3D5%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20curr.append%281%29%0A%20%20%20%20master.append%28curr%29%0A%20%20%20%20recur%28count,curr%29%0Amaster%3D%5B%5D%0Arecur%280,%5B%5D%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[image]

```
>>>def recur(count,current):
    count = count + 1
    if (count == 5):
        return
    current.append(1)
    master.append(current)
    recur(count,current)


>>> master=[]
>>> recur(0,[])
>>> master
[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> for i in master:
    id(i)


2485591104264
2485591104264
2485591104264
2485591104264
>>>
```

## Method 1

You can try this. There is no need to keep track of the `current` list you are appending to `master`.

```
def recur(count):
    count+=1
    if count==5:
        return
    curr=[1]*count
    #print(curr)
    master.append(curr)
    recur(count)
master=[]
recur(0)
print(master)
```

---

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

---

## Method 2

If you are keen on using `current` then try this.
Visualization for this code [click here.](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20recur%28count,curr%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20count%2B%3D1%0A%20%20%20%20if%20count%3D%3D5%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20curr.append%281%29%0A%20%20%20%20master.append%28curr%29%0A%20%20%20%20recur%28count,curr%5B%3A%5D%29%0Amaster%3D%5B%5D%0Arecur%280,%5B%5D%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=31&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

[image: Image 2]

```
def recur(count,curr):
    count+=1
    if count==5:
        return
    curr.append(1)
    master.append(curr)
    recur(count,curr[:])
master=[]
recur(0,[])
print(master)
```

---

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

## Method 3

Or you can try this.

```
def recur(count,curr):
    count+=1
    if count==5:
        return
    curr.append(1)
    master.append(curr[:])
    recur(count,curr)
master=[]
recur(0,[])
print(master)
```

---

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

---

## Method 4

If you want to return `[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]` then try this.

```
def recur(count,curr):
    count+=1
    if count==5:
        return []
    curr.append(1)
    return [curr]+recur(count,curr[:])
master=recur(0,[])
print(master)
another_master=recur(0,[])
print(another_master)
```

---

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below,

```
master = []

def recur(count, current):
    count += 1
    if (count == 5):
        return
    tmp = current[:]
    tmp.append(1)
    master.append(tmp)
    recur(count, tmp)

recur(0, [])

master
```

output

```
[[1], [1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```