# How can I get a sorted copy of a list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list `L = [2,0,4,5]`. How can I make a new list that is a sorted version of `L`, without changing `L`?

I tried `K = L.sort()`, but then `print(K)` prints `None`, and `L` becomes `[0,2,4,5]`.

Comment: The first item google returns for `python list sort` explains this. Did you try and figure this out yourself?

Answer (score 23):

The following will make a sorted copy of `L` and assign it to `K`:

```
K = sorted(L)
```

[`sorted()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) is a builtin function.

The reason `K = L.sort()` doesn't work is that `sort()` sorts the list *in place*, and returns `None`. This is why `L` ends up being modified and `K` ends up being `None`.

Here is how you could use `sort()`:

```
K = L[:] # make a copy
K.sort()
```

Comment: is sorted a method of list?

Comment: @user1817310 `sorted()` is a built-in function, methods are denoted by `.` notation , i.e `L.something()`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the builtin function `sorted`: `sorted(L)`