# How to get a list with an element removed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to do a job for each item in a list. But I got a problem.
I want **this code:**

```
list=[1,2,3]
for i in list:
  func(list.removed(i))
```

to do **this:**

```
func([2,3])
func([1,3])
func([1,2])
```

How can I make it? Thanks.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Are you sure that's the right duplicate?

Comment: There's got to be one, though.

Comment: That one looked good to me. It includes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15738712/3890632) which looks suitable.

Answer (score 2):

Using slices:

```
for i in range(len(xs)):
    func(xs[:i] + xs[i + 1:])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html) for that, by taking all [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) of the list of its size - 1:

```py
import itertools

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for comb in itertools.combinations(lst, len(lst)-1):
    print(comb)
```

Gives:

```
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 2, 4)
(1, 3, 4)
(2, 3, 4)
```