# python:list index out of range

Tags: python, indexing

my code is:

```
def my_sort(list):
    for _ in list:
        if list[0] > list[1]:
            list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]
    return my_sort(list[1:2])
```

but i keep getting this error:
IndexError: list index out of range

at this line:    if list[0] > list[1]:

this is the test code i am using:

```
   def test_my_sort():
lst_test = random.choices(range(-99, 100), k=6)
lst_copy = lst_test.copy()
lst_output = my_sort(lst_test)

assert lst_copy == lst_test, "Fout: my_sort(lst) verandert de inhoud van lijst lst"
assert lst_output == sorted(lst_test), \
    f"Fout: my_sort({lst_test}) geeft {lst_output} in plaats van {sorted(lst_test)}"
```

Comment: First: `list` is a very bad name for a variable because you overwrite the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list). Second: Are you sure that you have at least two elements in your list (hint: `list[1:2]`)?

Comment: 1- Do not use `list` as a variable name, as it is a reserved word. 2- Do not assign `list[0], list[1] = list[1], list[0]`. That might not work as you want it to. 3- You're returning `my_sort([1:2])` Which is causing your problem. You need to return `0:2`.

Comment: do a `print(list)` before your `for  _ in list:` line and share us the output

Comment: Could you explain what this function should do?

Comment: @Matthias recursive bubble sort

Comment: In that case the approach seems wrong. You always only compare and reorder the first two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem stems in this line:

```
return my_sort(list[1:2])
```

In python, we start indices from `0` and not from `1`. So this translates to "Indices 1 to 2". The index you "stop at" is not included, so your syntax becomes "Give me index 1". The correct solution would be:

```
return my_sort(list[0:2])
```

or better yet:

```
return my_sort(list[:2])
```

Since empty here means from start.

Edit:
I haven't solved your recursion issue, I only solved your list index issue. However, please do take a look at [this solution for a recursive bubble sort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51146466/1961688).

Comment: Did you try that? Did you not get a `RecursionError`?

Comment: thanks but if i do that it says that i have reached a recursion limit of 981 which is kinda weird since my lists have a max length of 6

Comment: @Matthias Nope, I just fixed his problem, not fixed his recursion.

Comment: @PascalVos Yes that's correct, as you don't have a case to stop at. All recursive functions need a stop case.

Comment: @PascalVos You're problem isn't fixed with this answer. This calls your function again and again with the same two elements.

Comment: so how do i tell it to stop when it has checked the last number?

Comment: Take a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51146458/bubblesort-with-recursion-in-python3-returning-none) @PascalVos, which was done a while ago.