# How to fetch existing table from database using sqlalchemy in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have 'device' table in my database, I am trying to fetch the that device object so i can update some record to that table . I have tried `meta = MetaData(bind=engine, reflect=True)` its working fine but showing some warning "SADeprecationWarning: The MetaData.reflect flag is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.   Please use the MetaData.reflect() method." When i am trying with `MetaData.reflect()` not getting the expected output .

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

db_url = {
         'drivername': 'postgres',
          'username': 'postgres',
          'password': '***',
          'host': 'localhost',
        'database': "test_db",
          'port': 5432}
engine = create_engine(URL(**db_url))
session_obj = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
meta = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine)
print(meta)
user_t = meta.tables['device']
sel_st = user_t.select()
conn = engine.connect()
res = conn.execute(sel_st)
for _row in res:
    print(_row)
```

Let me know what i am missing .

Comment: `meta = MetaData()`, then `meta.reflect(bind=engine)`. Now you bind the return value of `reflect()`, which is probably `None`. It is common in Python that methods that mutate the object return None: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list

Comment: @IljaEverilä yeah that's correct. But do you know how to implement the above scenario ?

Answer (score 2):

change this line

```
meta = MetaData().reflect(bind=engine)
print(meta)
user_t = meta.tables['device']
```

into

```
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
user_t= meta.tables.get('device')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When answering a question, try to **explain** what you are trying to achieve in your answer. Code only answers do not help the OP as much as code answers with explanations because the OP **understands** why they must do what you have done.