# Python Class Always Return None

Tags: python, list, class

I am creating an object that represents the hand of a blackjack player. One of the methods of the hand is to add a new Card to it. However, my Hand object always returns None when I attempt to print it.

Here is my code of the Hand object.

```
class Hand:
    '''An object representing the Card objects that the player has in their hands'''

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []

    def addCard(self, card):
        self.list = self.list.append(card)
        return self.list

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Your hand has {self.list}.'

myHand = Hand('Henry')
myHand.addCard(str(myCard))
print (myHand)
```

myCard is an object that returns "Four of Diamonds" I created previously. Below is the whole code if you are interested.

```
class Card:
''' A class for representing a single playing card. '''

def __init__(self, value, suit):
    ''' Creates Card object with given suit and value. '''
    self.value = value
    self.suit = suit

def getSuit(self):
    ''' Returns the suit of the Card. '''
    return self.suit
    
def getValue(self):
    ''' Returns the value of the Card. '''
    return self.value
    
    
def getBlackjackValues(self):
    ''' Get a list of possible Blackjack values for the card. '''
    # IMPLEMENT ME

    if 1 < self.value:
        BlackjackValue = self.value
        return [BlackjackValue]

    else:
        BlackjackValue = [self.value, 11]
        return BlackjackValue

def __str__(self):
    ''' #Return a string representation of the Card. '''
    # IMPLEMENT ME

    # Convert numerical values into letters
    if self.value == 2:
        Value = 'Two'

    elif self.value == 3:
        Value = 'Three'

    elif self.value == 4:
        Value = 'Four'

    elif self.value == 5:
        Value = 'Five'

    elif self.value == 6:
        Value = 'Six'

    elif self.value == 7:
        Value = 'Seven'

    elif self.value == 8:
        Value = 'Eight'

    elif self.value == 9:
        Value = 'Nine'

    elif self.value == 10:
        Value = 'Ten'

    elif self.value == 11:
        Value = 'Jack'

    elif self.value == 12:
        Value = 'Queen'

    elif self.value == 13:
        Value = 'King'

    elif self.value == 1:
        Value = 'Ace'

    
    # Convert suit values into letter
    if self.suit == 'S':
        Suit = 'Spades'

    elif self.suit == 'H':
        Suit = 'Hearts'

    elif self.suit == 'D':
        Suit = 'Diamonds'

    elif self.suit == 'C':
        Suit = 'Clubs'

    # The card is
    return f'Your card is {Value} of {Suit}.'

myCard = Card (4, 'D')
print (myCard)

class Hand:
    '''An object representing the Card objects that the player has in their hands'''

def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.list = []

def getName(self):
    return self.name

def getList(self):
    return self.list

def addCard(self, card):
    self.list = self.list.append(card)
    return self.list

def __str__(self):
    return f'Your hand has {self.list}.'

myHand = Hand('Henry')
myHand.addCard(str(myCard))
print (myHand)
```

Here is the screenshot of the output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7TcI.png)

Comment: `addCard` returns None. It doesn't have a return statement in it.

Comment: A relevant question on the `list.append` return value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list

Comment: @khelwood, thank you for the comment. I added return self.list, but the code still returns none. I edited the question.

Comment: @NguyenTran But `self.list = self.list.append(card)` is setting `self.list` to None, because `append` returns None. So you're still returning None.

Answer (score 1):

`list.append()` method works in place, i.e. it returns `None`. That is what you assign to `self.list`. Note that if you try to add second card it will raise an error, because `None` has no `append` attribute.

Comment: I do not quite understand this. Can you try to edit the code? It would be great help!

Comment: @Nja already edited their answer and now it provides the correct solution

Comment: The edited code from @Nja makes Python prints Your hand has None instead of None. I still can't find where is the None part is from.

Comment: No, that is not true, you made something different. With your Card class and their code it prints `Your hand has ['Your card is Four of Diamonds.'].`

Comment: I didn't edit anything else. I edit my question for it to include the whole code and also a screenshot of the output. Thanks in advance if you can take a look.

Comment: Look at your lines 115-117 (as visible in the screenshot) and compare with their code. As I said, they EDITED their answer to provide correct code solution after my answer.

Answer (score 1):

All I need to do is use .append() at the return statement in the addCard method.

Also, credits to @Nja for pointing out that I do not need to update myHand object again, but simply initiate the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Hand:
    '''An object representing the Card objects that the player has in their hands'''

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.list = []

    def addCard(self, card):
        self.list.append(card)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Your hand has ' + ' '.join(self.list)
myCard = "ciao"
myHand = Hand('Henry')
myHand.addCard(str(myCard))
print (myHand)
```

Comment: `Hand.addCard()` doesn't need to return anything

Comment: Yeah, sorry, a typo!

Comment: I think this is a step into the right direction. Instead of printing None, Python now prints Your hand has None.

Comment: Problem is that you need also to transform list into string. This can be a solution. Else define a class `Cards` with a `_str_` method for that. Here i solved it joining every string element.

Comment: The edited code of yours works alone, but I need to be able to add a Card object to the Hand object instead of just string. I edited the question for it to include the whole code with also a screenshot of the output. Can you help me take a look?