# print(sample_set.add('1232')) gives out put as None

Tags: python, function, printing

```
sample_set ={'a', 1234, 'xyz', 12.454}
print(sample_set.add('1232'))
```

Gives output as : `None`

What I am trying to understand is, why doesn't the nested '`.add`' function work and prints a set with an additional element `1232`?

Comment: exactly same question as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list

Comment: Python's design guidelines discourage the use of chained operations. Also builtin Python functions do not return what is already known (the set in this case).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't list operations return the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list)

Answer (score 0):

Because the method `add` doesn't return anything.

Just make the following change:

```
sample_set ={'a', 1234, 'xyz', 12.454}
sample_set.add('1232')
print(sample_set)
```