# Python: Convert tuple to list and insert() - in one expression?

Tags: python

I am trying to do something like this:

```py
my_list = list((1,2,3)).insert(0,0)
```

Is there a way to do that in one expression?

P.S. I am not trying to be economic with my lines, I'm just curious is that possible and how would one do it in python.

Comment: not a downvoter, but people dont tend to overly engage the use of one liners here, afaik

Comment: Well I was not suggesting that is a correct way or anything, I was just curious if that is possible in python and how it's done.

Comment: Not a downvoter as well, just a tip, try to look at your question objectively before posting and think of how to make it clearest possible. To me, for example it seems like the silly answer of "just do `my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3]`" will actually answer your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on python 3.8+ this is doable

```
>>> (my_list:=list((1,2,3))).insert(0,0)
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. Had to look up [:=](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Answer (score 1):

One slightly naive way is the following:

```
a = [0] + list((1,2,3))
```

`.insert()` (same as `.append()`, `.extend()`, etc) modifies the list but don't actually return anything, that's why you can't use them in a chained operation. See the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205638/10354789) about why this happens as a Python design choice.