# Removing number from list of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

I am trying to remove a number from a list of numbers but for the life of me I just can't make it work.

I tried using list.remove() method and .pop() but it is some how not working. largest is a function which returns the largest number in the list. I made a copy of the list as part of the question requirement is for the list not to be mutated. When i tried printing the bList i get None.

I also tried using .pop() by introducing a variable index = c.index(l) and the use the c.pop(index) that didn't work too.

````
def largest(aList):
    theLargest = aList[0]
    for i in range(1, len(aList)):
        if theLargest < aList[i]:
            theLargest = aList[i]
    return theLargest

def main():
    aList = [2,5,1,6]
    c = aList.copy()
    l = largest(c)
    bList = c.remove(l)
    print(bList)
main()
```
````

Comment: Maybe try: `bList = [x for x in aList if x != max(aList)]`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't list operations return the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`remove()` works in-place, which means `l` will be removed from `c` and that's it, it **won't** return a new list.

So you don't really need `bList`, you can just remove `l` from `c` and `print(c)`, like this:

```
def main():
    aList = [2, 5, 1, 6]
    c = aList.copy()
    l = largest(c)
    c.remove(l)
    print(c)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer and the explanation !

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:
def largest(aList):
theLargest = aList[0]
for i in range(1, len(aList)):
if theLargest < aList[i]:
theLargest = aList[i]
return theLargest

```
def main():
aList = [2,5,1,6]
c = aList.copy()
l = largest(c)
c.remove(l)
print(c)
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code:

```
def largest(aList):
    theLargest = aList[0]
    for i in range(1, len(aList)):
        if theLargest < aList[i]:
            theLargest = aList[i]
    return theLargest


def main():
    aList = [2, 5, 1, 6]
    c = aList.copy()
    l = largest(c)
    # create a list without the largest num
    bList = c
    bList.remove(l)
    print(bList)


# Call your main function
main()
```

**Output:**

```
[2, 5, 1]
```

The method `remove()` doesn't return a new list.
The `remove()` method removes the first matching element (which is passed as an argument) from the list.