# Is it possible to modify the list itself, not its copy?

Tags: python, list

I need to write a function which removes odd numbers from a list and square remaining even numbers.

I've tried something like this:

```
def modify_list(l):
    l1 = [i ** 2 for i in l if i % 2 == 0]
    return l1
```

but it creates a copy from a list that I've passed to a function, whereas I need to modify the passed list itself, so the following code would result:

```
id(l1) == id(l) # True
```

I've also tried to rewrite the code using `remove` method, but I couldn't figure out how to square remaining elements from passed list so it would return the same list (not its copy)

```
def modify_list(l):
    for element in l:
        if element % 2 != 0:
            l.remove(element)
```

Is it possible to change my code in order to return the same list object that I've passed, but without odd numbers and with squared even numbers?

Comment: Use list assignment? `l[i] = ...`?

Comment: Try using `lst[:] = ops on lst`

Comment: I disagree with the reason for closing this question, there are no answers related to how to remove elements from the list in-place in the link attached. I believe that this question was closed too hastily and that the person who closed it should have payed more attention.

Comment: An easy solution to this question would be to process the list in reverse order, popping the even numbers and assigning the squared value to the list index for the odd numbers.

Comment: @Vinzent - I think the slice assignment answers in the linked dupe are responsive - those modify the list in place. `l[:] = [i**2 for i in l if l % 2 == 0]` achieves the stated goal. Maybe room for expansion with techniques for working on a list that's sufficiently large that you'd prefer not making a temporary in-memory copy?

Comment: " whereas I need to modify the passed list itself" - in this case, please [follow Python convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list) and return `None` (rather, don't explicitly `return`) rather than the modified list.

Comment: @Vinzent The slice assignment mentioned by Daniel Hao above will do exactly what is required, and there are two answers at that other question which make use of this (in addition to any other answers of relevance). As such, I agreed that that question (found by another user) was a suitable duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

```
def modify_list(l):
    li = [i**2 for i in l if i % 0 == 0]
    for n,i in enumerate(li):
        l[n] = i
    return l
```

lists are mutable so a direct assignment works. 'li' is a new list so will have a different id.

Comment: Aside from the typo (`i % 0`), you are not changing the length of the list, even if the `if` evaluates False for some elements.

Comment: yup - sorry about typo and yes also, the original unchanged elements remain so  an extra step would be needed or better code??