# When a method has no return statement, how do I print out it's return value?

Tags: python, algorithm, syntax-error

EDITED.

I am learning about Linked Lists. For each process applied by a Method, it is printed out to the console. So, adding, removing, searching (i.e, displaying the result of a search), are all streamed to `stdout`, but I cannot seem to do this for the insertion Method even though the `insert` Method is executed.

Some Methods have a return statement, while others rely on the `__repr__()` for conversion to string, to then be streamed to the console. The insertion Method (not mine, but a course worked example) takes *two* arguments and does not have a return statement. The most consistent error message I get when attempting to print is `TypeError: %d format: a real number is required, not NoneType`, or `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`, where I have replaced `%d` with `%s`.

What I do not understand is, why I am unable to display test data for the insert Method, while I can do so for all others.
The code,

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Node:
  data = None
  next_node = None

  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<Node data: {}>".format(self.data)

# Linked List
class LinkedList:

  def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

  def is_empty(self):
    return self.head == None  # corrected

  def size(self):
    current = self.head
    count = 0

    while current:
      count += 1
      current = current.next_node

    return count

  # Adding a node
  def add(self, data):

    new_node = Node(data)
    new_node.next_node = self.head
    self.head = new_node
    

  # Searching the List
  def search(self, key):

    current = self.head

    while current:
      if current.data == key:
        return current
      else:
        current = current.next_node
    return None
  
  # Inserting into the List
  def insert(self, data, index):
    
    if index == 0:
      self.add(data)

    if index > 0:
      new_data = Node(data)

    position = index
    current = self.head

    while position > 1:
      current = current.next_node
      position -= 1

    past_node = current
    future_node = current.next_node

    past_node.next_node = new_data
    new_data = current.next_node

  # Removing a node from the List
  def remove(self, key):
    
    current = self.head
    previous = None
    found = False

    while current and not found:
      if current.data == key and current == self.head:
        found = True
        self.head = current.next_node
      elif current.data == key:
        found = True
        previous.next_node = current.next_node

    return current

  def __repr__(self):
    
    nodes = []
    current = self.head

    while current:
      if current is self.head:
        nodes.append("[Head: {}]".format(current.data))
      elif current.next_node is None:
        nodes.append("[Tail {}]".format(current.data))
      else:
        nodes.append("[{}]".format(current.data))

      current = current.next_node
    return '-> '.join(nodes)
```

Test output;

```py
l = LinkedList()
l.add(1)
l.add(2)
l.add(3)
l.add(5)
l.add(6)
l.add(7)

length = l.size()
print("Size of list: {}".format(length))  # Size of list: 6

print(l)  # [Head: 7]-> [6]-> [5]-> [3]-> [2]-> [Tail: 1]

seek = l.search(7)
print("Found: {}".format(seek))  # Found: <Node data: 7>

between = l.insert(4, 3)
if between is not None:
  print(f"Inserted {between} at index {between}")
else:
  print("A problem with code") # A problem with code

gone = l.remove(1)
print("Removed: {}".format(gone))  # Removed: <Node data: 1>

# Note the insertion of '4' at index 3
print(l)  # [Head: 7]-> [6]-> [5]-> [4]-> [3]-> [Tail: 2]
```

THIS CODE WORKS!

Other variants of the print format have been tried `f"{}", .format()` and even an attempt at conversion to string `str()` was made, with no luck. Could someone explain exactly what the problem is (though, I believe it to be a NoneType issue) and how to resolve it?

I hope my question is clearer. Thank you.

Comment: Your code seems to have several bugs and I get an error when I enter `between = l.insert(4, 3)`, before even getting to the `print`. Are you able to run up to that point without errors?

Comment: You are missing a colon at the end of line: `def __init__(self, data)` under the Node class. I cannot get this to work at all. Please produce a working example of your code. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_node'`

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. A function without a ``return`` statement *has no return value* to print (aside from the default `None`). What value do you expect ``between`` to have and why?

Comment: That `insert` method is wrong. If that is a "a course worked example" then please do yourself a favour and look for a better course.

Comment: I agree with MisterMiyagi; there seem to be some implicit assumptions about Python here that are incorrect, so explaining your reasoning should clarify the issue. From that final print-formatting code block, it seems like you might expect all functions to have some 'internal return value' equal to their passed-in arguments, but that this internal return value is only observable by using a return-statement or repr? If so, this is not accurate.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: thank you for your comment. I understand that a function without a return statement cannot return anything. Where I have gone wrong is not supplying the full implementation of the algorithm and specifically, the test output of each method. I shall delete this and start over. Sorry for wasting your time, all contributers.

Comment: The updated code still does not return anything in ``insert``, so there is still nothing (only `None`) to print. Can you clarify what you expected to happen?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: What I expected to happen was that as with the other Test codes, I would see a description of what the `insert` method had done. Forgive me; there is a `__repr__` close to the top of the script and one at the bottom of the script. They provide a string representation of the tested methods, except for the `insert` method. Why is this? Owing to a piece of data being a NoneType. How is this possible? I do not know; this is what I am trying to find out so that I can have a descriptive statement of the `insert` method's execution. It is not important. i would like to have it.

Comment: *"THIS CODE WORKS!"*: it doesn't. Just execute it like you put it here. It has syntax errors.

Comment: I think you are confusing some things. The ``print(l)`` show what the *state* of `l` is via `__repr__` (`__str__` would be more appropriate, by the way). That you ran some method before is incidental; it does not show what the methods did, it just shows what the state is *now*. All the other `print`s show what the methods *returned*, because they actively work with the return value; there is nothing to show for a method that does not return anything, because there is no return value.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: I accept what you say is correct. That I cannot output the return statement of the `insert` method is precisely because it does not have a return statement. I was wondering whether it was possible to do, under the circumstance. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several issues with the code you presented, including the following:

- The `Node` class should not define `data` and `next_node` as class attributes. They should be instance attributes. Luckily, the constructor creates an instance attribute `data` (hiding the class attribute), but for `next_node` this is not done, which makes your linked list unusable.
- In line with the previous comment, you should have `self.next_node = None` in your constructor.
- [*You corrected this in an edit to your question*: The method name is_empty suggests that it will return a boolean indicating whether the list is empty or not. But instead it makes the list empty. That seems wrong.]
- [*You corrected this in an edit to your question*: `insert` can call a method add which is not defined.]
- In `insert`, when `index` is 0, the code will still continue after the first `if` and reference a variable `new_data` that has not been defined (since the second `if` condition was not true). You should avoid that any of the other code is executed when `index` is 0. You can do this with a `return`.
- In `insert`, in the `while` loop there is no verification whether `current` is `None`. If that happens, `current = current.next_node` will raise an error.
- `new_data = current.next_node` is useless and leaves the `next_node` attribute of `next_node` uninitialised.
- Not an issue, but in `remove`, the `found` name is not very useful. Just break out of the loop when the node has been found and removed. Also, avoid having the `current.data == key` condition executed twice for the same node.
- In `remove`, in the loop, you never change `current` nor `previous`, and so the loop hangs.
- [*You corrected this in an edit to your question*: In the main code, the list is empty at the moment that `l.insert` is called, so it is strange to pass 3 as value for the `index` parameter, as that index is out of range. As mentioned in a previous bullet, this will trigger an error. If you want to add a node at index 3, you'll first have to add nodes at indexes 0, 1, and 2.]
- The `insert` method does not return anything, so capturing its return value is not going to give you anything else than `None`. If you really want to get some feedback from it, then do like you did for the `remove` method: have it return the relevant node. In that case you should also let `add` have a return value.

Here is some working code with the above issues addressed and more:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = None   # next_node neads to be an instance attribute, not a class attribute

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Node data: {}>".format(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head == None  # Don't MAKE it empty!

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next_node
        return count
    
    def add(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.next_node = self.head
        self.head = new_node
        return new_node  # Return the new node

    def search(self, key):
        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current.data == key:
                return current
            else:
                current = current.next_node
        return None

    def insert(self, data, index):
        if index == 0:
            # Don't continue after this call to self.add
            return self.add(data)  # Return the new node
        current = self.head
        while index > 1 and current:  # Protect against out of range index
            current = current.next_node
            index -= 1
        if current:  # Protect against out of range index
            new_data = Node(data)
            # Make sure the new node gets a next_node assignment
            new_data.next_node = current.next_node
            current.next_node = new_data
            return new_data  # Return the new node

    def remove(self, key):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        while current:
            if current.data == key:  # Check this only once per node
                if current == self.head:
                    self.head = current.next_node
                else:
                    previous.next_node = current.next_node
                break  # No need for variable - just exit
            previous = current           # Update previous
            current = current.next_node  # Move to next node
        return current

    def __repr__(self):
        nodes = []
        current = self.head
        while current:
            if current is self.head:
                nodes.append("[Head: {}]".format(current.data))
            elif current.next_node is None:
                nodes.append("[Tail {}]".format(current.data))
            else:
                nodes.append("[{}]".format(current.data))
            current = current.next_node
        return '-> '.join(nodes)

l = LinkedList()
l.add(1)
l.add(2)
l.add(3)
l.add(5)
l.add(6)
l.add(7)

length = l.size()
print("Size of list: {}".format(length))  # Size of list: 6

print(l)  # [Head: 7]-> [6]-> [5]-> [3]-> [2]-> [Tail: 1]

seek = l.search(7)
print("Found: {}".format(seek))  # Found: <Node data: 7>

node = l.insert(4, 3)
print("Inserted {}".format(node))  # Inserted: <Node data: 4>

gone = l.remove(1)
print("Removed: {}".format(gone))  # Removed: <Node data: 1>

# Note the insertion of '4' at index 3
print(l)  # [Head: 7]-> [6]-> [5]-> [4]-> [3]-> [Tail: 2]
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to review my code. I apologise; I was attempting to apply brevity to the question by abstracting the code to what I thought would be useful and functional; I failed to do this, for which, can only apologies to you and everyone else that contributed to the question. I will have to delete the question and start over because I have not clearly stated the problem, or provided a good enough example of the issue.

Comment: I cannot really appreciate that you changed the question as you did, and even applied a correction to it based on my answer.

Comment: Updated my answer in light of the update to your question. Last bullet point is possibly the one that interests you most.

Comment: It was not my intention to offend; I took on board the comments you and others made about the vagueness of my question and the errors in the submitted code. I tried to rectify the problems - not add to them. Nonetheless, thank you for looking into the question and providing an answer (which I have yet to review because I'm still trying to find the problem with the `print(f"Inserted {between} at index {between}")` line of code. A syntax error, but no idea how, or why. It may also have been that the shebang was missing(?)

Comment: I don't have that line in my answer, because I kicked the whole idea of `between` (also, it makes little sense to print `between` twice, suggesting it changes magically from being a value to an index).

Comment: Thank you. I think you could be right about finding a better course. Your implementation is a lot easier to understand, now that the extra variables have been discarded. Also, the test evaluations help me to see and know whether the implementation works, or not; the return statement for the `insert` method was essential; I had questioned its omission at the time I went through the exercise.

Answer (score 2):

`insert` does not "have a problem" outputting data - just like standard Python lists, it is an in-place operation. You are modifying the list on which it is applied.

`insert()` does not need to return anything, as all the information you need is provided by you when calling it - you need to pass a list, you need to pass data to insert and you need to pass an index at which the element is to be placed - there is no new information to be gained from returning anything.

Related question:
[Why don't list operations return the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-dont-list-operations-return-the-resulting-list)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing 2 things here. The value after the return statement is what the function call is replaced with when the function is called. So for example:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

square(4)
```

here the square(4) would be replaced with 4*4. And if you don't explicitly use a return statement than a None is returned after the last command in the function/method.

Whereas **repr**() is a way to specifiy the string representation of that object. So for example:

```
class A:
    pass

a = A()
print(a)
```

might create a cryptic output of <**main**.A at 0x7fbc841c9490>. So if you want it to be more descriptive you could add a **repr**() method:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Coordinates of the point are x: {self.x}, y: {self.y}"

p = Point(2,4)
```

And instead of the cryptic default message you'd get:

```
Coordinates of the point are x: 2, y: 4
```

So the representation is how the obj is converted to a string whereas the return value is what the function call is replaced with.

> print is TypeError: %d format: a real number is required, not
> NoneType, or TypeError: not enough arguments for format string, where
> I have replaced %d with %s.

So this creates errors because %d and %s expect numbers and strings when the return type of a method without return is None.

Comment: thank you for explaining how `__repr__` functions. I realise that in order to get the work of a `function`, it must have a `return` statement. I am loosely familiar with JavaScript; I am ignorant about Python.