# The insert function is returning None

Tags: python, insert

in python, I am trying to insert into a list recursively for a decimal to binary converter but the insert  it is returning none

```
def dectob(num):
  print(num)
  if num==0:
    return []
  hnum = int(num/2)
  if num - hnum == hnum:
    asn="0"
  else:
    asn="1"
  return dectob(hnum).insert(0,asn)
print(int(''.join(dectob(6666)))==1101000001010)
```

asn: answer

num: base ten number

hnum: integer of half of num

I tried everything I made this longer version so it prints all the data

```
def dectob(num):
  print(num)
  if num==0:
    print("got")
    blanklist=[]
    print(blanklist)
    return blanklist
  hnum = int(num/2)
  if num - hnum == hnum:
    asn="0"
  else:
    asn="1"
  ret= dectob(hnum)
  print(ret)
  print(asn)
  return ret.insert(0,asn)
print(int(''.join(dectob(6666)))==1101000001010)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods: clear / extend / reverse / append / sort / remove) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-clear-extend-reverse-append-sort)

Comment: Of course it is. Why did you *expect* it to return something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insert()` modifies the list in place but does not return a value. Typically with functional programming you avoid side effects and treat most data structures as immutable, so `insert()` is probably the wrong choice here. Instead of mututaing the returned list, you can simply return the result of recursion along with the new value:

```
def dectob(num):
    if num==0:
        return []
    hnum = int(num/2)
    if num - hnum == hnum:
        asn="0"
    else:
        asn="1"
    return dectob(hnum) + [asn]

int(''.join(dectob(6666))) == 1101000001010
# True
```

Comment: "Typically, with recursion you avoid mutating lists" huh? not sure that is typical or not.

Comment: I guess I didn't state that very well @juanpa.arrivillaga. Perhaps a better way to say it is that recursive functions are typically pure functions — i.e without side effects. In this case, that may not apply so well since the mutation is happening on the result of recursion.