# why update() in python returns None?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to merge between 2 dictionaries by using update() but I get "None" when I try to print the function's result

```
def merge_dictionaries(dict1,dict2):
     return dict1.update(dict2)

dict1 = {'Ten': 10, 'Twenty': 20, 'Thirty': 30}
dict2 = {'Thirty': 30, 'Fourty': 40, 'Fifty': 50}

print(merge_dictionaries(dict1,dict2))
```

why do I get None?

I tried to change the input values but nothing have changed/

Comment: `update` mutates an existing dictionary. It doesn't return a new one. It's not exactly a duplicate, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11205254/4996248) for a similar problem with lists.

Comment: The convention used by the standard library is to return `None` when a function or method modifies its argument or object in-place.

Comment: `dict.update` updates the dict in-place. If you want to return updated dict use `{**dict1, **dict2}` or `dict1 | dict2` in newer versions of python. Related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38987)

Comment: You're probably looking for `return {**dict1, **dict2}`.

Comment: "I tried to change the input values but nothing have changed/" they did change, check `print(dict1)`

Comment: Why are you expecting `.update()` to return something?  Have you read the documentation for that method?

Answer (score 1):

The update() method does not return a new dictionary with the updates, it just updates the dictionary in place.

.

This way you return the dictionary that has been updated:

```
def merge_dictionaries(dict1,dict2):
     dict1.update(dict2)
     return dict1
```

.

You should also consider other methods to merge the dicts, such as

- `{**dict1, **dict2}` syntax
- `ChainMap` class from the `collections` module
- dictionary comprehension
- `union()` method from the `merge_dict` library
- `dict1 | dict2` syntax

Comment: "When you give values to a function, you are actually parsing a copy of the values. So on this code, the actual dictionaries are not being changed, only the copies" - this is totally wrong. The dict **is** updated.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille you are right, I made a confusion. The answer is updated