# Assignment Python course

Tags: python

I have the following assignment from my python course:

#4. If a fruit doesn't exist in the list add the fruit to the list and print the modified list. If the fruit exists print('That fruit already exist in the list')

```
fruits = ['banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'lemon']

fruit_dennis = 'apple'

if fruit_dennis in fruits : print ('That fruit already exist in the list')
else: print (fruits .append (fruit_dennis) )
```

When i excecute it says None. Why is that?

Printed without the condition and it worked.

Comment: `fruits.append` doesn't return the updated list.

Comment: use `print` and `list.append` seperately

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-methods-append-sort-extend-remove-clear-reverse-return)

Comment: If you're following a Python course, I would also recommend you adhere to the formatting of Python.

Answer (score 1):

`fruits.append()` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`. You want to do this instead:

```py
fruits = ['banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'lemon']

fruit_dennis = 'apple'

if fruit_dennis in fruits: 
    print('That fruit already exist in the list')
else: 
    fruits.append(fruit_dennis)
    print(fruits)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the append function modifies your list in-place, while returning nothing.

you are printing (fruits.append(fruit_dennis)), so python will execute the append method before printing it, the append method will correctly place fruit_dennis in the list, and then return nothing for the print function to print.

```
fruits = ['banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'lemon']

fruit_dennis = 'apple'

if fruit_dennis in fruits: 
    print('That fruit already exist in the list')
else: 
    fruits.append(fruit_dennis)
    print(fruits)
```

this will be correct

Answer (score 0):

If you trace your code line by line, you will find apple gets appended to the list but append returns `None` so you print that instead of the list itself.

To fix it you can edit your code to print the updated list like this:

```
fruits = ['banana', 'orange', 'mango', 'lemon']
fruit_dennis = 'apple'
if fruit_dennis in fruits:
    print ('That fruit already exist in the list')
else:
   fruits.append (fruit_dennis)
   print (fruits)
```

this should work.

Answer (score -2):

1. You can use triple backticks for code `looks like this`
2. You did not print the list in the else condition.
   And also just a side note: It's really not recommended to ask people to solve your assignments.