# Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

Tags: python-3.x

```
nnl = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
y, x = nnl
l = ['' for i in range(y)]
supl = list(range(1, 1 + x))
for i in range(y):
    l[i] = supl.copy()
    supl = supl.reverse()
...
```

I need to create an array filled in the form of a snake like that:
1  2  3  4  5
10 9  8  7  6
11 12 13 14 15
got two variables: height and length:
3 5

But i got this Error and don' know how to solve  this problem

Comment: Read [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11205254/364696), but short version: `supl = supl.reverse()` should just be `supl.reverse()` (no assignment); `list.reverse` operates in-place and returns `None`.

Comment: Also, minor side-note: `l = ['' for i in range(y)]` is a verbose/slow way to spell `l = [''] * y` (sequence multiplication is unsafe if the contents of the `list` being multiplied are mutable, so you shouldn't do it for a `list` of `list`s, but it's perfectly fine when the contents are immutable objects like `str`, `int`, etc.).