# why does list(map(..)) return a list of None when using it with list.reverse?

Tags: python, list, in-place

Say

```
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
f = lambda x: x.reverse()
K = map(f,L)
# I want [[3,2,1],[6,5,4]]
```

theoretically, K is a map that reverses each sublist in L.

```
print(K) #prints some map
print(L) #prints [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

So far, L is not reversed. However,

```
print(list(K)) #prints [None,None]
print(L)       #prints [[3,2,1],[6,5,4]]
```

I assume that `print(list(K))` returns `[None, None]` since `list.reverse()` is an in-place function on L. However, the change is not applied when I call K, but it is applied when I insert K in an list. What is going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-methods-append-sort-extend-remove-clear-reverse-return)

Comment: @OneMadGypsy for `map(reversed,...)` remember that `reversed` returns an iterator, not a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct in identifying that `list.reverse()` is an in-place operation, meaning it changes the list itself and doesn't return a new list. That's why `None` is the output, as the `reverse` method doesn't return anything (its return value is `None`).

The thing to understand about `map` is that it doesn't execute the function on the elements of the iterable until you actually iterate over the map object. The map object is a sort of promise that says "I'll do this operation when you need the result".

In your code:

```py
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
f = lambda x: x.reverse()
K = map(f,L)
```

`K` is a map object, and the `reverse` operations haven't been performed yet. They're waiting to be performed when you iterate over `K`.

When you do `print(list(K))`, it converts `K` to a list, which involves iterating over `K`, which involves running `f` (the `reverse` operation) on each element of `L`. That's when the sublists get reversed. But `f` returns `None` because `list.reverse()` returns `None`, so what you get is a list of `None`s.

And now when you look at `L`, you see that it has been reversed. That's because the `reverse` operation was performed on its sublists when you iterated over `K`.

In summary, the changes were applied when you called `list(K)`, not when you created `K` with `map(f, L)`, and `list(K)` gave you `[None, None]` because `f` returns `None`.

If you want to use `map` and a lambda function to reverse the sublists, you can do it like this:

```py
L = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
f = lambda x: x[::-1]  # This creates a new list that's a reversed version of x
K = map(f,L)
print(list(K))  # prints [[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4]]
```

Here `f` creates a new list instead of reversing `x` in-place, so it has a list to return, and `map(f, L)` gives you the result you want. And it leaves `L` unchanged.