# Python convention indicating whether method chaining is method cascading?

Tags: python, method-chaining

I am spinning up on Python and Spark.  I noticed that Python uses a
lot of chaining of methods and/or properties.  A lot of what I found
online about this for Python describes method *cascading*, even though
it is referred to as method chaining.  According to
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining), *chaining*
returns an object, from which another method is invoked.  On the other
hand, *cascading* requires that the returned object is "self", so it
is a subset of chaining.

Is there a convention by which one can quickly recognize when
cascading is specifically being used as opposed to general chaining?  Here are two examples
I saw from a [PySpark
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark-tutorial/?expand_article=1):

```
df = spark.readStream
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.100:9092")
        .option("subscribe", "json_topic")
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") // From starting
        .load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(id AS STRING) AS key", "to_json(struct(*)) AS value")
   .writeStream
   .format("kafka")
   .outputMode("append")
   .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "192.168.1.100:9092")
   .option("topic", "josn_data_topic")
   .start()
   .awaitTermination()
```

It really helps to accelerate the figuring out of the code, especially
when one is unfamiliar with the ecosystem of classes in question.  In
cascading, it's just consecutive calls to methods of the same object.
Chaining that is *not* cascading, however, requires much more care in
deciphering, since the object could change part way through the chain.

Comment: You'd find much more of this in Ruby than in Python.

Comment: What you're calling "cascading" is called "fluent interface". It's not very common in Python.

Comment: A few libraries like Spark and SQLAlchemy use fluent interfaces. There's no easy way to recognize it, you just have to know what the style of the library is.

Comment: Thanks, Barmar.  Do you feel confident enough to post it as the answer?  As far as I'm concerned, it answers the question.  I think it's too bad that there is now way to recognize cascading.  Such discernment would accelerate the understanding of code.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205638/476. You will rarely find “cascading” at all in Python, unless the library goes against common Python design.

Comment: Thanks, deceze. So the answer is that method cascading is rare in Python because Guido van Rossum advises (requires?) that libraries be designed such that methods don't return *self* as a result of mutating *self*. In turn, the reason for this is to avoid confusion about whether a specific instance of method chaining is method cascading, essentially by (largely) eliminating the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is synthesized from links provided in comments by *Barmar* and
*deceze*.

Method cascading is rare in Python because Guido van Rossum advises (requires?) that libraries be designed such that methods don't return self as a result of mutating self.

In turn, the reason for this is to avoid confusion about whether a specific instance of method chaining is method cascading, essentially by (largely) eliminating the latter.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205638#11205638) is the cited source.