# why cant i extend two separated lists inside one big list

Tags: python, nested-lists

i have a list with three lists inside it iam trying to  turn it to one list that has all the items that were in the 3 seperated list and with the same order

so for example I have a list "B" which has 3 lists inside it. I ran for loop in a range of (len(B)-1) applying this command:

B[0]=B[0].extend(B[1])

But the value of B[0] became None . and I don't know why

small note: the problem that I'm solving is preventing me from using any if condition in my code

Comment: This may help flatten your list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-do-i-make-a-flat-list-out-of-a-list-of-lists ; as for the problem you come upon, `.extend` is an inplace method, which returns None: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-methods-append-sort-extend-remove-clear-reverse-return

Comment: I'd suggest a slightly different approach: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable

Comment: "But the value of B[0] became None . and I don't know why" - because that's what `.extend` returns, and you assign that result. Please see the linked duplicate.

Comment: "i have a list with three lists inside it iam trying to turn it to one list that has all the items that were in the 3 seperated list and with the same order" - then instead of asking about your approach tothe problem, you should simply ask about that task.

Answer (score 0):

The `extend` list method destructively modifies the list and returns `None`.  So the assignment

```
B[0]=B[0].extend(B[1])
```

first modifies `B[0]` by extending it, then replaces it with `None` due to the assignment.  You can replace it with:

```
B[0].extend(B[1])
```

That will destructively modify `B[0]` by extending it with `B[1]`.  It's equivalent to `B[0] += B[1]`, which also destructively modifies `B[0]`.

This explains what your code is currently doing, but it doesn't solve your problem.  If you just want to create a new list which is the concatenation of the sublists, you can do:

```
new_list = sum(B, [])
```

This creates a new list consisting of the concatenation of the sublists.

Comment: You can even replace it with `B[0].extend(B.pop(1))` to remove B[1] at the same time you extend B[0].