# control flow logic for creating new file

Tags: python, try-except

I'm setting up a function that aims to export data as a text file. The function is called frequently with new data being generated. I'm trying to insert some control logic that handles if exported data already exists or not.

**So 1) where text file exists, then append new the data and export. 2) where text file does not exist, create new text file and export.**

I've got a try/except call as 99% of the time, the text will already exist.

Where there is no existing text file, the func works fine through the except path. But where there is a text file, both the try and except paths are triggered and I get the export from except.

**The specific question I have is how is the except being triggered when the `try` section is initiated?  If `try` is used, shouldn't the `except` be obsolete?**

```
def func():
    try:
        with open("file.txt", 'a+') as file:
            data = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
        newdata = ['d','e','f']
        alldata = data.append(newdata)
        with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
            for row in alldata:
                output.write(str(row) + '\n')
    except:
        data = [['a','b','c']]
        with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
            for row in data:
               output.write(str(row) + '\n')

func()
```

Intended output:

1. where the text file does not exist, the output should be:

   `[['a','b','c']]`
2. where the text file does exist, the output should be:

   `[['a','b','c'],`
   `['d','e','f']]`

Edit 2:

```
def func():
    try:
        with open("file.txt", 'r') as file:
            data = [line.rstrip() for line in file]
        newdata = ['d','e','f']
        data.append(newdata)
        with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
            for row in data:
                output.write(str(row) + '\n')

    except FileNotFoundError:
        data = [['a','b','c']]
        with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
            for row in data:
               output.write(str(row) + '\n')

func()
```

Comment: For the first open? Will include

Comment: Beside the point, but [a bare `except` is bad practice](/q/54948548/4518341). Use the specific exception you're expecting like `except FileNotFoundError`, or at least `except Exception`.

Comment: Why aren't you taking advantage of the `a+` mode you're using? With that code, you might as well use `r`.

Comment: Oh actually, it's not beside the point. `for row in alldata` will be an error because `alldata` is `None`.

Comment: What's the question exactly? Please [edit] to clarify. If you weren't already aware, Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not just a code help site. See the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Ok. I'll look to incorporate `FileNotFoundError` within the except. I'll be more specific with the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-methods-append-sort-extend-remove-clear-reverse-return)

Comment: As pointed out by others you don't need that except block given you're using `a+` mode. That except block is actually handling the error caused by trying to iterate over `None`. Another point you should note is that you're writing the string representation of a list to a file, you should consider more suitable alternatives like JSON instead since parsing those string representations is considerably more difficult.

Comment: @Jerryj123 The question you added doesn't make sense because the accepted answer doesn't answer it, plus I already told you the answer to that question ("`for row in alldata` will be an error" / "bare except is bad practice") and in any case, if you want to know what error is happening, you just have to remove the error handling. So, please either change the question or un-accept the answer. That said, I realize this is messy since we're trying to rework this post after the fact.

Comment: ... Actually, maybe there's more to your question, I'm not sure. One thing I'm not sure if you're clear on is that a `try` block will **always** be initiated; it's only when an error occurs that execution moves to the `except` block. If you want to review how it works, check out the Python Tutorial: [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions). To be clear, I thought you were asking "Why is my code erroring", but now I'm not sure if you might be asking something more like "How does try-except work".

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, thankyou. that link helped. I have amended `alllogs` to `logs`, which has fixed the appending error of `None`

Comment: @wjandrea, it was probably both. It was initially not understanding how try-except works until I found out that returning `None` was causing the issue

Comment: I have included Edit 2. This flow has rectified the previous issue. While the accepted returned the same end result it may not have answered the question. I could probably delete the question perhaps? Would at least return some reputation points! I'll also look into JSON values as there were some parsing hurdles to jump with string representations

Answer (score 1):

```
def func():
    newdata = ['d','e','f']

    try:
        # Open file to read existing data and then append
        with open("file.txt", 'r+') as file:
            data = [line.strip() for line in file]
            file.seek(0)  # Move pointer to the start of the file
            if data:
                # Convert string representation of list back to list
                data = eval(data[0])
            else:
                # Initialize data if file is empty
                data = []
            data.append(newdata)  # Append new data
            file.write(str(data) + '\n')  # Write updated data
            file.truncate()  # Truncate file to current position

    except FileNotFoundError:
        # Create file and write data if it doesn't exist
        with open("file.txt", 'w') as output:
            data = [newdata]
            output.write(str(data) + '\n')

func()
```

Comment: `data = eval(data[0])` is highly questionable. 1) It's data, not an arbitrary expression, so you should be using [an appropriate data parser](/q/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list) instead of a [possible security vulnerability](//nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) (since OP hasn't said if the file is trusted, though it is implied). 2) Why are you replacing `data` with an element of itself? If you're going to do that, at least use a different name.

Comment: The eval should not be used, along with exec, they are forbidden functions